# How to redirect or reroute other url mappings to base name url's in react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to redirect all other url's to the default basename url:
Eg:

```
<Router basename="test">
  <Routes>
   ......
  </Route>
  </Router>
```

If i hit the url /any it should redirect to /test, how to configure this in react router,I know that default route is not an option because url doesn't start with /test in this case?

Answer (score 0):

To define the default not found route don't use path:

```
<Router basename="test">
    <Switch>
      ...
      <Route component={NotFound}/>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: No, I want to redirect every other url which doesn't start with /test (i.e basename) for example /example to be redirected to /test